# .htaccess Rewrite Folder Issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

So I have the following folder structure:

```
-public_html/
   - .htaccess
   - web/
       - index.php
       - rt/
           -index.php
```

The .htaccess contains the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^rt/(.*)$ web/rt/$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

The idea is that any urls starting 'rt' are directed to 'web/rt' (such as /rt/ and /rt/secure/) and everything else goes to 'web'. For some reason the 'rt' redirect does not work and everything is going to 'web'. Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

Examples:

```
/                 > web/index.php
/my_page/         > web/index.php
/rt/              > web/rt/index.php
/rt/another_page/ > web/rt/index.php
```

Comment: Thanks Justin but adding 'RewriteBase /' did work.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that 2nd rule is rewriting everything even the target of the first rule.

You can have:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^rt/(.*)$ web/rt/$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(?!web/)(.*)$ web/$1 [NC,L]
```

Now 2nd rule will skip any URI that starts with `/web/`.

Comment: Thanks for this response, but it did not work for this issue.

Comment: Clear your browser cache and tell what URL is not working and what's the error.

Comment: Cache cleared, no URLs are working that start /rt/. The error is a 404 which is rendering its content from the 'web' folder and not the 'rt' folder.

Comment: Is there any other .htaccess in your system? Do you have any other rule in this .htaccess?